# Black view when starting new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my android application I want an automatically refresh every 60 seconds. So I tried it like this:

```
public void refresh_check() {
        Thread myThread = new Thread()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (counter < 60) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                counter += 1;
                                System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        refresh();
                    }});
                super.run();
            }
        };
        myThread.start();       
    }
```

This works in the way that it prints the counter into logcat but in my Application I get a black view. `refresh()` is just a function with a http request, and this works alone, so the mistake has to be in the thread at any place :/ Can someone help?

Comment: Why do you run it on the UI thread? This will block operation.

Comment: Because the refresh function calls some other functions which update Textviews etc

Comment: You can use TextView.post(Runnable) to update the TextViews from outside the UI Thread. Or you can use AsyncTask to make your processing in doInBackground() then update the TextViews with the results in onPostExecute()

Comment: I got it now. Did it with a handler, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not utilizing the `Thread` correctly. Running long tasks on the UI thread is just like not using a `Thread` at all. To accomplish what you need you should do it like this:

```
public void refresh_check() {
        Thread myThread = new Thread()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (counter < 60) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                counter += 1;
                                System.out.println("Counter: " + counter); //I think this may cause exception, if it does try removing it
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        refresh(); // In refresh(), use TextView.post(runnable) to post update the TextView from outside the UI thread or use handlers
                    }});
                super.run();
            };
        myThread.start();       
    }
```

Also, take a look at AsyncTask class, it enables you to run long tasks outside UI thread (`doInBackground()`) as well as update UI with the result from (`onPostExecute()`)